# Find $n$ sets such that $A_i\cap A_j\ne\emptyset$ and $A_i\not\subseteq A_j$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Can we find $n$ sets such that the pairwise intersection of any two is non-empty and no set is a subset of another?

Here is an example for $n=4$:

[image: 4 sets]

Comment: Yes. Pick them all to be $\{0\}$. (I think you wanted to add something else to your question.)

Answer (score 4):

Take $A_n = \{0,n\}$ for every $n>0$. Then $A_n \cap A_m = \{0\} \neq \emptyset$, and none of them is included in another.

Answer (score 4):

Make the sets $A_i$ the petals of a flower:

[image]

where each petal is taken to intersect the flower's center.

Comment: Best diagram today

Comment: Now this is good answer.

Comment: @TlönUqbarOrbisTertius I like your username :)